# how to do query constraint in parse api using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, parse-platform

I am newly using to this queries in parse api. I need how to give exact url by using jquery ajax so far i am trying like below

```
var query = encode('where={"city":"chennai","cheatMode":false}' );
            $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/cities?"+query,
        dataType:"json",
        headers:{
            "X-Parse-Application-Id":"KEY",
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "KEY",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
```

Can you please tell me how to filter based on specific city name?

Comment: try data: JSON.stringify('your json')

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
     "city": "chennai",
     "cheatMode": false
 };
 var query = encodeURIComponent('where='+ JSON.stringify(obj));

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/cities?" + query,
     dataType: "json",
     headers: {
         "X-Parse-Application-Id": "KEY",
             "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "KEY",
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried the above code but i am getting all cities, not getting specific city. what would be the output from data.results

Comment: I tried your edited answer,  this time it was showing null.... first time i am using this parse api, their docs given only example of curl and python.I don't understand how to solve this query constraint

Comment: I have got $ has not defined,how can use jquery in parse.com express.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the format of your ajax req is wrong. This is the format I use for my POST reqs to parse server.

```
                var serverUrl = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/parse/classes/Evaluation';

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'xxxx');
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'xxxx');
                        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
                    },
                    url: serverUrl,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        first_name: first_name,
                        last_name: last_name,
                        email: email,
                        address: address,
                        country: country,
                        location: location,
                        token: token
                    }),
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (success) {
                        console.log(success);
                        // Stripe payment token saved to prase server
                        $('#js-evaluation-result').animate({ 'opacity': '1.0' }).html('<p class="help-block text-success">' + success_msg + '</p>').delay(3000).animate({ 'opacity': '0.0' });
                        $("#js-evaluation-btn").text('Yay');

                        // Go to thankyou page after 2 seconds
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location.href = "https://www.yourdomain.com/success/evaluation";
                        }, 1500);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        $('#js-evaluation-result').animate({ 'opacity': '1.0' }).html('<p class="help-block text-danger">' + error_msg + '</p>').delay(3000).animate({ 'opacity': '0.0' });
                        $("#js-evaluation-btn").text('Done');

                        // Go to thankyou page after 2 seconds
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location.href = "https://www.yourdomain.com/error/contact";
                        }, 1500);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                beforeSend: function (request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'xxx');
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'xxx');
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
                },
                url: serverUrl,
                data: "where=" + escape(JSON.stringify({ "email": $('#treatment-payment-form').find('input[name="email"]').val() })),
                processData: false,
                success: function (success) {
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```